# Filter array of objects by another object's values

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I would like to filter an array of objects based on the values in another object. I am trying to `map()` the array and `filter()` inside the function so that I am able to get a new array with only the desired (active) fields.

I am trying to get the filter on the `Object.entries()`, I try to compare the keys and check if the values of the active filters are `true`, but I am not getting it right.

```js
const records = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "first",
    date: "05/02"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "second",
    date: "06/02"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "third",
    date: "07/02"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "fourth",
    date: "08/02"
  }
];

const active = {
  id: true,
  name: false,
  date: true
};

const result = records.map((record) => {
  return Object.entries(record).filter((entry) => {
    Object.entries(active).forEach((activeEntry) => {
      return activeEntry[1] && activeEntry[0] === entry[0];
    });
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

This is the desired outcome

```js
const desiredOutcome = [
  {
    id: 1,
    date: "05/02"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    date: "06/02"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    date: "07/02"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    date: "08/02"
  }
];
```

Comment: 1. `.forEach()` doesn't return anything, And the `return` in the callback is mostly meaningless. 2. you have no `return` in the `.filter()` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter over the entries of the object and convert it back to an object with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
const records=[{id:1,name:"first",date:"05/02"},{id:2,name:"second",date:"06/02"},{id:3,name:"third",date:"07/02"},{id:4,name:"fourth",date:"08/02"}];
const active = {
  id: true,
  name: false,
  date: true
};
const res = records.map(x => 
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(x).filter(([k])=>active[k])));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply filter the keys by the key existing and then use `Object.fromEntries` to go back to an object

```js
const records = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: "first",
    date: "05/02"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "second",
    date: "06/02"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "third",
    date: "07/02"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "fourth",
    date: "08/02"
  }
];

const active = {
  id: true,
  name: false,
  date: true
};

const result = records.map((record) => {
  return Object.fromEntries( Object.entries(record).filter(([key,value]) => active[key]));
});

console.log(result);
```